# Can I get a tourist visa for Nicaragua without a complete return ticket?

Tags: visas, nicaragua

I'm going on a trip to Nicaragua, and will continue on to Costa Rica and Panama and travel from there. I'm an EU citizen, and from what I have read, tourist visas are issued on the spot without issues.

I have so far booked a return flight from Miami to Oslo, but I haven't booked the flight to Miami, as I wanted to be flexible later.

Will this create any problems in getting a visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your onward ticket to Costa Rica / Panama should be sufficient IMHO. [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true), the system used by airlines, says:

> All visitors are required to obtain a Tourist Card on arrival. Fee: USD 10.-
>
> Extension possible. Fee: USD 2.- per day of stay.
>
> Warning
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.